# Use GRUB/GRUB2 to PXE boot OS image

Tags: windows, networking, script, bootloader, grub

Here is the situation I am in:

I currently have a Windows drive that boots XP. The BIOS does not support PXE booting so this is out of the question. Therefore, I was thinking I could install a customized GRUB bootloader on it instead such that it will have the option to PXE boot an image from a DHCP server connected to it and have the option to load Windows as it normally does (two items in menu). The catch is it may need to be automated (meaning no keyboard), so is there any way to run a script pre-boot during GRUB loading that determines if DHCP / TFTP servers are running and attempt to PXE boot an image from the network (and if not, say timeout of 10 seconds, regularly boot from Windows drive)?

If this is not possible, what are some other options / suggestions? I was reading up on grub4dos as well but I'm not sure that is what I need. FWIW, I'm free to do whatever I want to the drive. I'd really appreciate some help on this as I'm not sure where to start. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like it might be a superuser or serverfault question.

Comment: I've seen GRUB questions asked here so I figured it was okay. I apologize if this is the wrong place for it.

Comment: It was more a suggestion than anything else. I don't have a "migrate" button anyway.

Comment: Thanks, posted it there, but was hoping someone here had input (seems like there is a lot more help available here).